# std::Xran and std::Xlen Errors

Tags: c++

When compiling a C++ program with Visual studio 2013, i get the error:

```
1)Error 49  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl    std::_Xlen(void)" (?_Xlen@std@@YAXXZ)    

2)Error 50  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl std::_Xlen(void)" (?_Xlen@std@@YAXXZ)   

3)Error 48  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl std::_Xlen(void)" (?_Xlen@std@@YAXXZ) referenced in function "public: class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > & __thiscall std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> >::append(unsigned short const *,unsigned int)" (?append@?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@QAEAAV12@PBGI@Z)   

4)Error 47  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl std::_Xran(void)" (?_Xran@std@@YAXXZ) referenced in function "public: class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > & __thiscall std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> >::assign(class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > const &,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?assign@?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@QAEAAV12@ABV12@II@Z)
```

I have googled this issue on the web, But none of answers can solve my problem. Could anyone give me some tips on how to solve this issue?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: a C program which uses std::string? Something's fishy.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: `basic_string<unsigned short` isn't really used much anymore. You might want to use [`wchar_t` as a distinct type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/dh8che7s.aspx) instead of as a `typedef`.